# Implement producer-consumer in Java with BlockingQueue seems losing data after consume

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I tried to build a API in Spring Boot, every time `saveRecord` is called, it will be run in a thread from ThreadPool. What I intend to do is buffer records in the `BlockingQueue`, when the size is greater than 400, take 400 records out of the `BlockingQueue` and put to file (only for testing).

```
private int putRecordBatchSize = 400;
private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
private BlockingQueue<String> buffer = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2000, true);

@Async
public void saveRecord() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    int cur = counter.incrementAndGet();
    if(buffer.add(cur+"\n") == false)   {
        logger.error(format("buffer add failed. buffer_remaining_cap=[%d]", buffer.remainingCapacity()));
    }

    if(buffer.size() >= putRecordBatchSize) {
        logger.info("[PutRecordBatch] start.");
        List<String> drainedRecords = new ArrayList<>(putRecordBatchSize);
        buffer.drainTo(drainedRecords, putRecordBatchSize);

        //TODO test code
        drainedRecords.stream().forEach(k -> {
            try {
                Files.write(Paths.get("text.txt"), k.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000); // mocking time-consuming operation
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        logger.info("[PutRecordBatch] end.");
        buffer.clear();
    }
}
```

But from the text.txt, it seems like the data added to the Queue between the start and end of `drainTo` operation is missing somehow, which looks like below. Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

```
389
390
391
392
393
394
395
396
397
398
399
400  // This is the border for every drainTo operation
430
431
432
433
434
435
436
437
438
439
```

Comment: `buffer.add()` can never return false. You probably want to use `buffer.offer()`.

Comment: Thanks man : )  @shmosel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it's no surprise that you are losing records:

```
buffer.drainTo(drainedRecords, putRecordBatchSize);
```

removes `putRecordBatchSize` elements from the `buffer`.

After writing out those records, you do a

```
buffer.clear();
```

which removes those elements that have been added while you were processing the previous elements.

Since `buffer.drainTo(drainedRecords, putRecordBatchSize);` already removes the elements that you are processing there is no need for `buffer.clear();`!